# Upgrading SQL Server (2014) Express to Standard

Tags: sql-server, licensing, sql-server-2014, microsoft

I have a server running SQL Server 2014 Express Edition that is fast approaching the 10GB limit for a database.

I've now purchased SQL Server 2014 Standard and wish to use it. SQL Server is no longer available by boxed copy, so, I purchased it on Open with the relevant CALs.

When I go to VLSC, I am only given the option to download the ISO files to perform a fresh install - I have done this countless times on fresh installs without issue.

However, when you go in to the setup for Express, you do have the option to change versions if you have a serial key:

[image]

I have tried contacting Microsoft without any luck what so ever.

I was wondering if anyone can help as I would obviously prefer to input a small key and change the license rather than having to reinstall over the top.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: @GregAskew - I already have the license, this question is about how to upgrade/change from Express to Standard from a software/technical perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `\x64` folder there is a file called `DefaultSetup.ini` where the PID will be. Once you copy the PID from there, run the setup and choose edition upgrade as you've already shown and input the PID copied from the file.

Comment: Thank you for this - I have that key now. I've been researching this for the best part of a day and just can't really see any references to upgrading editions other than a white paper for changing versions (e.g. 2012 express > 2014 standard). Is this a fully supported way of doing it or will I be causing problems for myself later?

Comment: @WilliamHilsum Fully supported, you should be fine. It will need to restart the service to take effect, so there will be a slight downtime.

Comment: Unfortunately, this key doesn't seem to work - the edition from the server is "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86)   Feb 20 2014 19:20:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (WOW64)", and, I used the defaultsetup.ini file from the 2014 download with the file "SW_DVD9_SQL_Svr_Standard_Edtn_2014_W32_English_MLF_X19-34509.iso"... I don't suppose you can offer any more assistance? ... https://imgur.com/a/nhCGO

Comment: @WilliamHilsum if you downloaded that from the volume licensing site then it should work if you run the setup from standard edition media. If it isn't, there isn't any further I can help and you'll need to speak with someone.

Comment: Hi Sean, this was run from the express installation centre that was installed previously (not using any media/downloads). I'll try it started from the standard setup disk. Thanks for your assistance.